# Reading and Printing multiple files into one outfile

Tags: python, file, io

When reading and printing through my files, printing through my cousole gives me the correct result, but writing to the outfile does not

```
with infile as f :
    lines = f.readlines()

new_line = " "

for line in lines:
    new_line = ''.join(line).replace('*',letter.upper())
    new_line = new_line.replace(':',letter.lower())
    print(new_line)
```

This prints out all of the letters that I inputted

```
with infile as f :
    lines = f.readlines()

new_line = " "

for line in lines:
    new_line = ''.join(line).replace('*',letter.upper())
    new_line = new_line.replace(':',letter.lower())
    outfile.write(new_line)
```

It only gives me the last letter of the word inputted.

```
folder = r"C:\Users\sarah\Documents\a CPS 111\Bonus PA\stars\stars"
# os.listdir(folder) returns a list of files in folder
file_list = os.listdir(folder)
letter_art = {}

word = str(input("Please input a letter: "))  
word = word.upper()

for fname in file_list:

    letter_extension_list = fname.split(".")

for letter in word:
    key = letter
    value = letter_extension_list[1]
    value = "%s."%(key) + value 
    letter_art[key] = value 

    fname = "\\".join([folder, value])

    infile = open(fname, "r")
    outfile = open("word_art.txt", "w")


    with infile as f :
        lines = f.readlines()

    new_line = " "

    for line in lines:
        new_line = ''.join(line).replace('*',letter.upper())
        new_line = new_line.replace(':',letter.lower())

        print(new_line)
        outfile.write(new_line)






infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

This is the code I am currently working with. I am taking in symbols from a txt file and changing them to the coornading letter depending on what the user inputed

Comment: Are you opening and closing the output file on each iteration?

Comment: Why are you doing `''.join(line)`, by the way? From what I can see, it should already be a string.

Comment: As I suspected, you are indeed opening the file anew on each iteration. You have `for letter in word:` and in that loop there's `outfile = open("word_art.txt", "w")`, reopening and wiping the file each time it's executed.

Comment: How can I fix this problem? do I need to put the outfile in the loop? @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the output file before the loop instead of within it:

```
outfile = open("word_art.txt", "w")
for letter in word:
```

Comment: Okay this fixed the biggest issue! Is there a way to print the two files next to each other opposed to vertically (this is what I'm eventually trying to achieve)? Because the last line of the first letter and the first line of the second letter are getting printed together @TigerhawkT3 .

Comment: I added outfile.write("\n") outside of the for line in lines loop and it fixed the first problem. But is there a way to get the letters horizontal opposed to vertical? @TigerhawkT3 .

Comment: I have updated my code and question! Thank you so much for your help with my first problem! @TigerhawkT3 .

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("test.txt",'r') as f :
lines = f.readlines()

with open('out.txt','w') as outfile: 
    for line in lines:
        new_line = line.replace('*',letter.upper())
        new_line = new_line.replace(':',letter.lower())
        outfile.write(new_line)
```

This worked for me.

EDIT:
TigerhawkT3 is correct. I checked out your full code and you were opening the file again and again inside the loop, each time discarding the prior changes.